# How can i change the visibility of a textview in every element of the recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an arraylist (called Itemlist) of all recyclerview elements. In each element there are 2 textviews - a german and english word. only one of them is shown (because they overlap). when i click on the element it shows the other language (for example: the german word is set to gone and the english word is visible now).

Now I want a function which sets all english textviews (in every element) to gone and the german to visible. My problem is - i dont know how to reach all elements in this arraylist and check the visibility of the textviews. in my example it resets only the first word.

[For better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4ILb.png)

Here is the code:

```
fun reset_to_EN() {

    ItemList.forEach { test_if_german() }
}
```

OR

```
fun reset_to_EN2() {

    for (item in ItemList) {
        test_if_german()
    }
}
```

Check visibility

```
fun test_if_german(){

    if (text_view_de.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        text_view_en.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        text_view_de.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

If you can please show me a code example for better understanding.

Thanks to everyone who tries to help.

---

Or here is the whole code for the adapter and mainActivity if it's needed:

```
class Adapter(
        val c: Context,
        private val ArrList: ArrayList<Item>):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>()
{

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(inflater)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = ArrList.size

    inner class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v), View.OnClickListener {

        var textViewDe: TextView = v.text_view_de
        var textViewEn: TextView = v.text_view_en
        private var menueImage: Button

        init {
            v.setOnClickListener(this)
            textViewDe = v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_de)
            textViewEn = v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_en)
            menueImage = v.findViewById(R.id.menu_button)
            menueImage.setOnClickListener { popupMenu(it) }
        }

        private fun popupMenu(v:View) {
            val drop = PopupMenu(c, v)
            val position = ArrList[adapterPosition]

            drop.inflate(R.menu.drop_menu) 
            drop.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                when(it.itemId){
                    R.id.edit_menu->{
                        val v2 = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.add_item_layout,null) 
                        val DE = v2.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)        
                        val EN = v2.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText2)
                        AlertDialog.Builder(c)                               
                            .setView(v2)                                     
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok"){
                                    dialog,_->
                                position.Englisch = DE.text.toString()
                                position.Deutsch = EN.text.toString()
                                notifyDataSetChanged()
                                //Toast.makeText(c,"User Information is Edited",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                dialog.dismiss()

                            }
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel"){
                                    dialog,_->
                                dialog.dismiss()

                            }
                            .create()
                            .show()
                        true
                    }
                    R.id.delete_menu-> {
                                ArrList.removeAt(adapterPosition)
                                notifyDataSetChanged()
                                //Toast.makeText(c,"entfernt",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                        true
                    }
                    else -> true
                }

            }
            drop.show()
            val popup = PopupMenu::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPopup")
            popup.isAccessible = true
            val menu = popup.get(drop)
            menu.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon",Boolean::class.java)
                    .invoke(menu,true)


        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

            if (textViewDe.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                textViewDe.visibility = View.GONE
                textViewEn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                textViewDe.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                textViewEn.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = ArrList[position]
        holder.textViewDe.text = currentItem.Deutsch
        holder.textViewEn.text = currentItem.Englisch
    }
```

And MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

//DEFINITION
    private lateinit var addButton: FloatingActionButton
    private lateinit var ItemList: ArrayList<Item>
    private lateinit var recy: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: Adapter

//ONCREATE
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//FINDVIEWBYID
        addButton = findViewById(R.id.addingBtn)
        ItemList = ArrayList()
        recy = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)

//RECYCLERVIEW
        adapter = Adapter(this, ItemList)
        recy.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recy.adapter = adapter

//FUNCTION-CALL
        addButton.setOnClickListener { addInfo() }
        }

//FUNKTIONENS
    private fun addInfo() {
        val inflter = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        val v = inflter.inflate(R.layout.add_item_layout, null) //
        val eng = v.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val deu = v.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText2)

        val addDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

        addDialog.setView(v)                        
        addDialog.setPositiveButton("OK"){ dialog, _->
            val eng2 = eng.text.toString()
            val deu2 = deu.text.toString()
            val UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
            ItemList.add(Item(UUID, eng2, deu2))
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Adding Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        addDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){ dialog, _->
            dialog.dismiss()

        }
        addDialog.create()
        addDialog.show()

    }

    fun clearData() {

        ItemList.clear()                               
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alles gelöscht", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    fun reset_all_EN() {
        //ArrayList = ItemList
        val size: Int = ItemList.size

        for (i in 0 until size) {

            if (text_view_de.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                text_view_en.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                text_view_de.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
    }

    fun reset_to_EN() {

        // using forEach() method
        ItemList.forEach { test_if_german() }
    }

    fun reset_to_EN2() {

        for (item in ItemList) {
            test_if_german()
        }
    }

    fun test_if_german(){

        if (text_view_de.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            text_view_en.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            text_view_de.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

//MENU CLASSES
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.open_menu -> {

                val intent = Intent(this, InfoActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            R.id.open_menu2 -> {

                val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            R.id.reset_all -> {

                reset_to_EN2()
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't see any declaration of `text_view_de` or `text_view_en`, I'm guessing you're using synthetic view properties from the deprecated Android Kotlin Extensions. Assuming that is the case:

When you use `text_view_de`, it is performing a search in your view hierarchy for the first view it finds with the matching ID. So even though you are doing it within a for loop that iterates through your list of items, you are only working with the same view, over and over.

*Edit:*
I realized you want to be able to toggle individual views and you were only asking how to **add** a button to reset all views back to the same language. If this is the case, it does not make sense to add a property to the adapter that controls the state of all views at once like I had suggested in the previous revision of this answer.

Instead, you need to change your data model to have a Boolean that determines which specific language that specific item should show. The problem with how you're doing it now in your click listener is that it is trying to use the Views themselves to determine what state the item is when you change it, but this will cause weird glitches when items scroll off of the screen and back on because ViewHolders get recycled and assigned to different items when they go off and back on screen.

To get started, add a Boolean for the state of the item to your Item class. I don't know exactly what your class looks like now, so adapt this as needed:

```
data class Item (
    val UUID: Long, 
    val english: String, 
    val deutsch: String, 
    var isShowDeutch: Boolean = true
)
```

A good practice is to have your Adapter class expose a callback for items being clicked so the outside class (Activity) is responsible for manipulating the data model and the Adapter's responsibility is limited to connecting data to views, not manipulating data. So create a callback that the Activity can implement that toggles a single Item's `isShowDeutsch` property. And when you bind data to a view, use that item's `isShowDeutsch` to determine visibility.

In Adapter class:

```
var onItemClickListener: ((itemPosition: Int)->Unit)? = null

//...

    // In ViewHolder:
    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        itemClickListener?.invoke(adapterPosition)
    }

//...

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = ArrList[position]
    holder.textViewDe.text = currentItem.Deutsch
    holder.textViewEn.text = currentItem.Englisch
    holder.textViewDe.isVisible = currentItem.isShowDeutsch
    holder.textViewEn.isVibible = !currentItem.isShowDeutsch
}
```

In your Activity when you set up your adapter, you can define a click listener for it that toggles the state of that single item and notifies the adapter of the change:

```
//RECYCLERVIEW
adapter = Adapter(this, ItemList)
recy.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
recy.adapter = adapter
adapter.onItemClickListener = { position ->
    ItemList[position].apply { isShowDeutsch = !isShowDeutsch }
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
}
```

And finally, to reset all items back to their original language, you can iterate the items in your list and then notify the adapter. This is more appropriate to do in your Activity, since the Adapter should not be responsible for manipulating data.

```
fun resetLanguage() {
    for (item in ItemList) {
        item.isShowDeutsch = true
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

I also recommend you change `lateinit var ItemList: ArrayList<Item>` to `val ItemList = ArrayList<Item>()`. It is error prone to have a mutable list type in a mutable `var` property because there are two different ways to change it and it creates the possibility of having your adapter looking at a different list than the one your Activity is working with.

Comment: OK. I have revised my answer. I'm deleting my comments above that are no longer relevant.